# How to make changes that only i can see?

Tags: git, local

For example Id like to modify the login page, so it auto-logs me.

I want those changes to **ONLY** work on my development station and dont be visible in push. if I make it on a branch than i would have to somehow un-merge that change before every push.

is that supported by git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use setup a [gitattributes filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)?

[image: smudge]

Every time to checkout your directory, it will check through a script in the `smudge` step) for that file (and that file only) if certain condition are met (as in "this is or is not your development station") and will modify the content accordingly.
The `clean` step would restore its content or at least ignore that particular modification.

Answer (score 7):

If you have at least Git 1.7.0, you might like this bit of ‘plumbing’:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- path
```

From the [`git update-index` manpage under “Skip-worktree bit”](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html):

> Skip-worktree bit can be defined in one (long) sentence: When reading
>           an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git pretends its
>           working directory version is up to date and read the index version
>           instead.
>
> To elaborate, "reading" means checking for file existence, reading file
>           attributes or file content. The working directory version may be
>           present or absent.

The “skip-worktree bit” is the basis for the [sparse checkout mechanism documented in the `git read-tree` manpage`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout).

---

There is a related ‘bit’ in older versions of Git (`git update-index --assume-unchanged`), but it should not be used for the OP's purpose. [It seems like it might be useful for the OP's situation](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3cfcaeb9bf0912150005w356744a0j6f543fd4bd2449e%40mail.gmail.com%3e), but [Git's maintainer has said that its contract (the “promise”) makes it unsuitable for such purposes](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3c7v39y7mglb.fsf%40alter.siamese.dyndns.org%3e).

Comment: I guess the second line is supposed to be: `git update-index --skip-worktree -- path`

?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question: why can't you just branch off? Have `master` your main, public branch and keep rebasing your private branch on `master` (or merging master with your private branch). Never bring your chances to `master`, only bring changes from `master` to your private branch.

If you happen to make changes on your private branch that you'd like to share with `master` there's no problem to cherry-pick the changes onto master.

Comment: but this way i will ALWAYS have to remember to NOT include that change(and i will forget about it sooner or later). is there some way to write script to ignore that change in merging?

Comment: If you really want to block yourself from exposing these changes then you can clone your repository elsewhere, but not add any remote in that clone that points to a public repository. Then, any change you make in that repository stays there: there's no remote you can push to. Of course, you can still get these changes exposed if you pull from that private clone, but that would require a different kind of explicit act than what you usually do. You usually _push_ your local repositories onto public ones, not _pull_ from your local clones onto other local repositories.