# Git doesn't show file as modified or let me commit in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I am having this random problem with source control on Xcode. I already had Git integrated with my project, but now it's not recognizing that changes have been made to some files and won't let me commit them.

The A never turns to M and the file does not get grayed out showing that it needs to be saved.

Comment: You need to commit file first, not just do the save.

Comment: I have noticed the same on my MAC. After I run the project sucessfully after save. I then try to Commit in XCODE - version Control and the .m was showing before save as M. But in commit , the comparison of the files is blank. 

Where in Terminal I have to be to make the GIT to work.

Answer (score 1):

Generally 2 possibilities:

- Either your files have been added in a `.gitignore` file,
- or their index is no longer set to be updated:
  See "[How to make a commit, or a change permanently local](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456667/6309)".

```
git  update-index --assume-unchanged -- /path/to/file
# Or:
git update-index --skip-worktree -- /path/to/file
```

The first check would be to see if a git status in a shell session shows the same issue (a modified file which wouldn't show in `git status`)