# Committing a file exactly one time in git

Tags: git

Is there a way to commit a file into a git repo *exactly* one time and then effectively make the file read-only as far as the repo goes?

For instance, I have a configuration file that contains some credential information that I don't want stored in a repo but I want the structure of the config file itself stored as a template for the next person who checks out the repo to re-hydrate.

Is this something that can be done at the repo level?

Comment: Don't store the configuration file in the repository. Put its name in `.gitignore`, remove it from the index and commit if it was committed before. Store in the repository a sample configuration file with a name that has a different termination or a suffix (usually `.dist` is added to the name). Fill the sample configuration file with default values, where possible, and empty or dummy values for sensitive information like usernames, passwords etc. Add enough comments (use a file format that allows them) to make it easy to be customized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make changes that only i can see?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749726/how-to-make-changes-that-only-i-can-see)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common use-case with projects, and should not be done the way you are specifying.

A more ideal approach would be creating a *sample* properties file, and not including a real one one in git.

Create a file named like **project.sample.properties**

```
# Local Configuration
user =
pass = 

# Defaults
server = example.com
```

Then with git, you would commit the sample, and ignore the user's.

In your **.gitignore**

```
project.properties
```

And make the commit

```
$git add .gitignore
$git add project.sample.properties
```

As part of the environment setup instructions, you should specify that local configuration must be done, or add an enforcement to a maven / ant build script.