# Untrack files on gitignore but still maintain file in origin

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to maintain some config files with default config in origin but continue modifying this files locally.

If I stop track this files, git removes this on origin too. The .git/info/exlude is not an option because this is only for one person locally and I need this for a team.

Any ideas what I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make changes that only i can see?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749726/how-to-make-changes-that-only-i-can-see)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+configuration+file